# C++ for_each algo and string

Tags: c++, foreach

I'm trying to loop through every letter of a string using for_each,

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> dico;
std::for_each(str.begin(),str.end(),[&](std::string l){
if(dico.count(l) == 0){
     ' DO SOMETHING HERE
})
```

However, I got one error message:

```
Error   2   error C2664: 'void `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda2>::operator ()(std::string) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char' to 'std::string'
```

I tried to change to `char l`, however, it would break `dico.count(l)`. Instead, I have seen others using `for loop` instead. That solution worked. However, I wonder why `for_each` would not work here.

Comment: That's how `std::for_each` work, it take each single item in the container (each character in the case of `std::string`) and passes them to your function. If you had e.g. a vector of strings, your lambda would work fine though.

Comment: but how to fix the error, given that the for_each is kept

Comment: If you tell us what you want to do, what problem you are trying to solve, we can help you better. Because your code will simply not work as presented, the only way to "fix" it is to change the lambda to take a `const char` as argument, which of course breaks your lambda in other ways, so at the moment your problem is unfixable.

Comment: @STNYU it will work only when `str` is a vector of string, or `dico` comprises of `char` as keys. You need to add details of your problem.
If you simply think `for_each` looks "cooler", that's not how programming should be done, else tell your problem statement more precisely

Comment: i figured changing the type in lambda was not enough. i should have changed the definition of unordered_map as well so that the compile would pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> dico;
    dico["a"] = 1;
    dico["b"] = 1;
    dico["c"] = 1;
    std::string str("abcd");
    std::for_each(str.begin(),str.end(),[&](char l){
        std::string s(1,l); // fixed
        if(dico.count(s) == 0){
            std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
        }});
```

This should work.

The problem is that you can not initialize a `string` using `char`, you need either another `string` (C++ string) or a `const char*` (C string).

Besides you might actually define a `std::unordered_map<char, unsigned int>`?

---

Edit based on comment by Rob Kennedy:

Fix incorrect use of `const char* cc = &l`.

Now calling correct ctor of `std::string`.

Comment: I tested char `c = 'c'; const char* cc = &c; std::string s(cc);` and you are right, `cc` is not a valid string. But somehow the codes works with no problem inside the lambda (`cc` inside lambda is valid string), that's confusing me now.

Comment: tested this again and `cc` is valid again: `void eatchar(char c) { const char* cc = &c; std::string s(cc); }`, so is this caused by UB?

Comment: Ok I found the correct ctor of `std::string`...shoulda read the cppreference before posting :p

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what exactly is str? What is its type and what does it contain?

Second, dico contains nothing and so, even if your code was correct and did compile, that branch would execute for every item in str.

Third, get the logic right first. Do it using a simple for loop. The more complex the code is, the longer you will spend trying to figure out the problem.

Finally, if you're just trying to use some C++11 features, start with the simpler ones, like the for range loop :)

```
for(auto l : str){
 if(dico.count(l) == 0){
   // do something
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

std::unordered_map::value_type is  pair
NOT string!

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> dico;
std::for_each(str.begin(),str.end(),[&](pair<std::string, unsigned int> l){ 
if(dico.count(l.first) == 0){
 ' DO SOMETHING HERE
})
```

it should work.

Comment: Why do you think that would work? Read the code carefully. Also read the question carefully, especially the cited error message. You've offered a fix for something that isn't a problem.